# What is the specific FAA regulation with regards to a pilot dropping jumpers into a solid cloud base?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, instrument-flight-rules, weather, parachute

What is the FAA regulation with regards to a pilot dropping jumpers into a solid cloud base?  I saw some parachute jumpers come through a solid cloud layer with a base at around 1300 AGL.  They landed maybe 1/2 mile from the airport on either side of a fairly busy four lane state road.  The cloud layer was solid 1600 AGL to 3000 AGL (we flew IFR and I recorded when we entered and when we got above the cloud blanket).  We were above this solid layer for 2 hours of our 3 hour flight.  Once home, I looked for the FAA regulation with regards to pilot's rules when dropping jumpers in such conditions but could not find any.  It is dangerous for the jumpers, the cars on the highway and for IFR pilots flying in the vicinity but but is it regulated by the FAA?